# jQuery Plugin breaks with this.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a plugin and trying to wrap the function inside of an each method but it breaks the plugin. If the block content is not wrapped within "this.each" plugin works. I understand that in order to pass multiple selectors I need to "return this.each" or not? I also want to eliminate the need to use the selector inside the plugin e.g "#the_lead", instead use "this".

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.scroll_lead = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            speedup: 500
        };
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        return this.each(function () {
            var $window_height = $(window).height();
            var $document_height = $(document).height();
            var $hide_lead;
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                var $scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                if (!$hide_lead) {
                    if ($scrollTop > ($document_height / 2)) {
                        $("#the_lead").slideDown(options.speedup);
                    } else {
                        $("#the_lead").slideUp(500, function () {
                            $(this).hide();
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            $('#hide_lead').click(function (e) {
                $(this).parent().parents('div').hide();
                hide_lead = true;
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you show us the rest?  How does it break the plugin?  Are you saying when you don't wrap it in `this.each` it works?  Do you get an error?

Comment: @ExplosionPills yes, if i don't wrap it in this.each it works... no error... i added the rest...

Comment: Can you give us an example use of the plugin on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Seems to be working here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Sb7dJ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things;

1. Assign $(this) to $this and use it inside any function inside your plugin, said in the tutorial, http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring.

   ```
   return this.each(function () {
       var window_height = $(window).height();
       var document_height = $(document).height();
       var hide_lead;
       $this = $(this);
       $(window).scroll(function () {
           var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
           if (!hide_lead) {
               if (scrollTop > (document_height / 2)) {
                   $this.slideDown(options.speedup);
               } else {
                   $this.slideUp(500, function () {
                       //$(this).hide();
                   });
               }
           }
       });
       $this.click(function (e) {
           $(this).parent().parents('div').hide();
           hide_lead = true;
           e.preventDefault();
       });
   });
   ```
2. Try to avoid manipulation of parent objects inside your plugin, including $(window), and $(document).

   It is ok to read properties of window and document, but if it is manipulated in your plugin, it will be maniuplated by number of times of your selector.

   In your code, because you use this.each, you are binding scroll function of window several times. For example, $("div").scroll_lead() will bind 'scroll' method to window as many as  tags of your document. The same applies to $(document) and all parent elements of plugin target.
3. If possible and it is your intention, use element scroll method, not window scroll.

   To get scroll value $(el).scrollTop()

   To scroll down, $(el).scrollTop(NUMBER)

   To bind onScroll method, $(el).scroll( functtion() {...} )

Hope it helps

Comment: I understand the premise of point 2 above but how would you code this in the real world so the 'each' loop doesnt bind to window/document for each node?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your syntax is incorrect.

`each` would not exist on `this` as this is the context of the function, and not an element that jquery knows about.

try `$(this).each` which would get you closer.

remember [Jquery.Each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) cannot iterrate over something that is not an object or array, so make sure that what you are trying to achieve makes sense.

What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure of the use of return this.each() on plugins. in my case I'm invoking on scroll() so not sure. This helped a lot