# jQuery plugin - best way to return this.each()

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have tried to make the smallest possible jquery plugin for floating elements when they are at the to of the page (thus, no defaults or options) but although the following works fine for 1 'sticky' element, I have issues making it work on multiple elements. I realise I need to return this.each but cant work out the best way. Surely I dont want the resize and the scroll in the each loop?

Code below:

```
(function ( $, undefined ) {
    $.fn.sticky = function() {
        var self = this,
            isStickyWidth = self.data('sticky'),
            isStickyActive = false,
            windowHeight,
            elOffset = self.offset().top,
            elHeight;
        $(document).on("scroll", function(){

            if(isStickyActive && windowHeight > elHeight) {
                var scrollPos = $('body').scrollTop();
                if(scrollPos > elOffset) {
                    self.css({'position':'fixed','top':'0px'});
                } else {
                    self.css({'position':'relative'});
                }
            }
        });
        $(window).on("resize", function(){
            windowHeight = $(window).height();
            elHeight = self.height();
            self.width(self.parent().width());
            if(isStickyWidth < $(window).width() ) {
                isStickyActive = true;
            } else {
                isStickyActive = false;
            }
        }).resize();
        return this; //need to return each in this example if binding to multiple DOM elements
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: You don't need to "return" `this.each`, since `this.each() === this`.

Comment: But as soon as there is more than one class sticky in the HTML it wont work properley as each sticky class/node has can have a different data-sticky attribute in the HTML. In the jQ docs it mentions 'If you want to do any manipulating with specific elements (e.g. getting a data attribute, calculating specific positions) then you need to use .each() to loop through the elements.'

Comment: Sure, I didn't say you don't have to _use_ `each`. But writing `return this.each` is not necessary at all. You should use `each` inside the scroll and resize handlers. Store `isStickyActive` using `.data()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is your code modified to iterate through each selector, and allows for chaining.

```
(function ( $, undefined ) {
    $.fn.sticky = function() {
    return this.each(function(){        
        var self = this,
            isStickyWidth = self.data('sticky'),
            isStickyActive = false,
            windowHeight,
            elOffset = self.offset().top,
            elHeight;
        $(document).on("scroll", function(){

            if(isStickyActive && windowHeight > elHeight) {
                var scrollPos = $('body').scrollTop();
                if(scrollPos > elOffset) {
                    self.css({'position':'fixed','top':'0px'});
                } else {
                    self.css({'position':'relative'});
                }
            }
        });
        $(window).on("resize", function(){
            windowHeight = $(window).height();
            elHeight = self.height();
            self.width(self.parent().width());
            if(isStickyWidth < $(window).width() ) {
                isStickyActive = true;
            } else {
                isStickyActive = false;
            }
        }).resize();
    }):

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: but isnt it bad to bind to scroll on multiple nodes? e.g. point 2 here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14780771/275119